# GCC snprintf with custom registered specifier

Tags: c, gcc, printf, buffer-overflow

What is the behaviour of GCC when I use `snprintf()` with a custom specifier (for example `%b` for binary)?

Is this code safe?:

```
alx_printf_b_init();
snprintf(str, 2, "%b", 5);
```

I believe it is unsafe, because the code responsible of printing the binary number doesn't know the size of the buffer.  Maybe there's a way to receive the length of the buffer in the code that registers the specifier.

The code to register the specifier is the following (source: [libalx](https://github.com/alejandro-colomar/libalx/), written by me):

```
/******************************************************************************
 ******* headers **************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#include "libalx/base/stdio/printf/b.h"

#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <printf.h>


/******************************************************************************
 ******* macros ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#define BIN_REPR_BUFSIZ (sizeof(uintmax_t) * CHAR_BIT)


/******************************************************************************
 ******* enums ****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* structs / unions *****************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
struct  Printf_Pad {
        char    ch;
        int     len;
};


/******************************************************************************
 ******* static functions (prototypes) ****************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
static  int     printf_b_output     (FILE *stream,
                                     const struct printf_info *info,
                                     const void *const args[]);
static  int     printf_b_arginf_sz  (const struct printf_info *info,
                                     size_t n, int *argtypes, int *size);

static  uintmax_t printf_b_value    (const struct printf_info *info,
                                     const void *arg);
static  int     printf_b_bin_repr   (bool bin[BIN_REPR_BUFSIZ],
                                     const struct printf_info *info,
                                     const void *arg);
static  int     printf_b_bin_len    (const struct printf_info *info,
                                     int min_len);
static  int     printf_b_pad_len    (const struct printf_info *info,
                                     int bin_len);
static  int     printf_b_print_prefix   (FILE *stream,
                                     const struct printf_info *info);
static  int     printf_b_pad_zeros  (FILE *stream,
                                     const struct printf_info *info,
                                     int min_len);
static  int     printf_b_print_number   (FILE *stream,
                                     const struct printf_info *info,
                                     bool bin[BIN_REPR_BUFSIZ],
                                     int min_len, int bin_len);
static  char    printf_pad_ch       (const struct printf_info *info);
static  int     printf_pad_spaces   (FILE *stream, int pad_len);




/******************************************************************************
 ******* global functions *****************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
int     alx_printf_b_init   (void)
{

    if (register_printf_specifier('b', printf_b_output, printf_b_arginf_sz))
        return  -1;
    if (register_printf_specifier('B', printf_b_output, printf_b_arginf_sz))
        return  -1;

    return  0;
}


/******************************************************************************
 ******* static functions (definitions) ***************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
static
int     printf_b_output     (FILE *stream,
                             const struct printf_info *info,
                             const void *const args[])
{
    struct  Printf_Pad  pad = {0};
    bool    bin[BIN_REPR_BUFSIZ];
    int     min_len;
    int     bin_len;
    int     len;
    int     tmp;

    len = 0;

    min_len = printf_b_bin_repr(bin, info, args[0]);
    bin_len = printf_b_bin_len(info, min_len);

    pad.ch = printf_pad_ch(info);
    if (pad.ch == ' ')
        pad.len = printf_b_pad_len(info, bin_len);

    /* Padding with ' ' (right aligned) */
    if ((pad.ch == ' ')  &&  !info->left) {
        tmp = printf_pad_spaces(stream, pad.len);
        if (tmp == EOF)
            return  EOF;
        len += tmp;
    }

    /* "0b"/"0B" prefix */
    if (info->alt) {
        tmp = printf_b_print_prefix(stream, info);
        if (tmp == EOF)
            return  EOF;
        len += tmp;
    }

    /* Padding with '0' */
    if (pad.ch == '0') {
        tmp = printf_b_pad_zeros(stream, info, min_len);
        if (tmp == EOF)
            return  EOF;
        len += tmp;
    }

    /* Print number (including leading 0s to fill precission) */
    tmp = printf_b_print_number(stream, info, bin, min_len, bin_len);
    if (tmp == EOF)
        return  EOF;
    len += tmp;

    /* Padding with ' ' (left aligned) */
    if (info->left) {
        tmp = printf_pad_spaces(stream, pad.len);
        if (tmp == EOF)
            return  EOF;
        len += tmp;
    }

    return  len;
}

static
int     printf_b_arginf_sz  (const struct printf_info *info,
                             size_t n, int *argtypes, int *size)
{

    (void)info;
    (void)size;

    if (n > 0)
        argtypes[0] = PA_INT;

    return 1;
}

static
uintmax_t printf_b_value    (const struct printf_info *info,
                             const void *arg)
{

    if (info->is_long_double)
        return  *(unsigned long long *)arg;
    if (info->is_long)
        return  *(unsigned long *)arg;
    if (info->is_char)
        return  *(unsigned char *)arg;
    if (info->is_short)
        return  *(unsigned short *)arg;
    return  *(unsigned *)arg;
}

static
int     printf_b_bin_repr   (bool bin[BIN_REPR_BUFSIZ],
                             const struct printf_info *info,
                             const void *arg)
{
    uintmax_t   val;
    int     min_len;

    val = printf_b_value(info, arg);

    memset(bin, 0, sizeof(bin[0]) * BIN_REPR_BUFSIZ);
    for (min_len = 0; val; min_len++) {
        if (val % 2)
            bin[min_len]    = 1;
        val >>= 1;
    }

    if (!min_len)
        return  1;
    return  min_len;
}

static
int     printf_b_bin_len    (const struct printf_info *info,
                             int min_len)
{

    if (info->prec > min_len)
        return  info->prec;
    return  min_len;
}

static
int     printf_b_pad_len    (const struct printf_info *info,
                             int bin_len)
{
    int pad_len;

    pad_len = info->width - bin_len;
    if (info->alt)
        pad_len -= 2;
    if (info->group)
        pad_len -= (bin_len - 1) / 4;
    if (pad_len < 0)
        pad_len = 0;

    return  pad_len;
}

static
int     printf_b_print_prefix   (FILE *stream,
                                 const struct printf_info *info)
{
    int len;

    len = 0;
    if (fputc('0', stream) == EOF)
        return  EOF;
    len++;
    if (fputc(info->spec, stream) == EOF)
        return  EOF;
    len++;

    return  len;
}

static
int     printf_b_pad_zeros  (FILE *stream,
                             const struct printf_info *info,
                             int min_len)
{
    int len;
    int tmp;

    len = 0;
    tmp = info->width - (info->alt * 2);
    if (info->group)
        tmp -= tmp / 5 - !(tmp % 5);
    for (int i = tmp - 1; i > min_len - 1; i--) {
        if (fputc('0', stream) == EOF)
            return  EOF;
        len++;
        if (info->group  &&  !(i % 4)) {
            if (fputc('_', stream) == EOF)
                return  EOF;
            len++;
        }
    }

    return  len;
}

static
int     printf_b_print_number   (FILE *stream,
                                 const struct printf_info *info,
                                 bool bin[sizeof(uintmax_t) * CHAR_BIT],
                                 int min_len, int bin_len)
{
    int len;

    len = 0;

    /* Print leading zeros to fill precission */
    for (int i = bin_len - 1; i > min_len - 1; i--) {
        if (fputc('0', stream) == EOF)
            return  EOF;
        len++;
        if (info->group  &&  !(i % 4)) {
            if (fputc('_', stream) == EOF)
                return  EOF;
            len++;
        }
    }

    /* Print number */
    for (int i = min_len - 1; i; i--) {
        if (fputc('0' + bin[i], stream) == EOF)
            return  EOF;
        len++;
        if (info->group  &&  !(i % 4)) {
            if (fputc('_', stream) == EOF)
                return  EOF;
            len++;
        }
    }
    if (fputc('0' + bin[0], stream) == EOF)
        return  EOF;
    len++;

    return  len;
}

static
char    printf_pad_ch       (const struct printf_info *info)
{

    if ((info->prec != -1)  ||  (info->pad == ' ')  ||  info->left)
        return  ' ';
    return  '0';
}

static
int     printf_pad_spaces   (FILE *stream, int pad_len)
{
    int len;

    len = 0;
    for (int i = pad_len; i; i--) {
        if (fputc(' ', stream) == EOF)
            return  EOF;
        len++;
    }

    return  len;
}


/******************************************************************************
 ******* end of file **********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
```

Comment: *Maybe there's a way to receive the length of the buffer..* - This is what the second parameter of `snprintf` is for? How is it unique to a "custom" specifier anyway?

Comment: Yes, `snprintf` recieves it, but AFAIK it isn't passed to the function that actually writes to the buffer, which AFAIK is `printf_b_output`.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you are asking...

Comment: Maybe GCC uses an internal buffer before writing to the user's buffer, in which case it could be safe, but I doubt it.  Another option is that the buffer's size is being passed but I didn't realize.

Comment: Well, apparently the code is using an internal buffer of size `BIN_REPR_BUFSIZ`

Comment: I use that buffer to store the binary base representation of the number, to later apply beautification such as alignment or digit separation, but the function does write to the user's buffer in the end.  I ignore the mechanism, because GCC only provides me with a `FILE *stream`.  Maybe there's magic behind that stream.  To clarify, that code is mine, not GCC's

Comment: Take a look at [vsnprintf](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libiberty/vsnprintf.c) implementation. It is using an internally allocated buffer (obtained from `vasprintf`), and then copying only the specified length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback you provide to the glibc printf custom specifier functionality does not involve buffers at all. The custom handler you write is responsible for writing the output to a stdio `FILE *` stream it receives as an argument, which might be a special type of stream referring to a string buffer or one of a number of other special types. Your code shouldn't care.

The only buffer in this code is defined internally (not as part of the interface with the extension API), and is sized as:

```
#define BIN_REPR_BUFSIZ (sizeof(uintmax_t) * CHAR_BIT)
```

which is a hard upper bound on the number of binary digits needed to represent any integer type.